# Using the Windows Azure Service Management Api from WAAD Application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Today I noticed that in the configuration of Windows Azure Active directories, a new entry showed up under web apis.

Seems that I can now allow my application access the Windows Azure Service Management Api in the same way we previously accessed Windows Azure AD Graph.

I am wondering what kind of RequestedPermissions scopes I can pass to the consensus granting. So far I have only used DirectoryReaders.

Before when accessign Graph API, this code worked:

```
    string tenantId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(TenantIdClaimType).Value;

    // Get a token for calling the Windows Azure Active Directory Graph
    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, LoginUrl, tenantId));
    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(AppPrincipalId, AppKey);
    AuthenticationResult assertionCredential = authContext.AcquireToken(GraphUrl, credential);
```

I simply tried the same thing for the management api using WAML.

```
    assertionCredential = authContext
        .AcquireToken("https://management.core.windows.net/",credential);


    using (var azure = new SubscriptionClient(new TokenCloudCredentials(assertionCredential.AccessToken)))
    {
        var subs = await azure.Subscriptions.ListAsync();
    }
```

The request failed though. "Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription". The error message is out of date, as its not been updated to handle tokens yet.

My guess is that I need to request access when doing the consensus with the user.

Comment: I am feverishly working with Vittorio to put together a detailed walk-through of how to accomplish this. We're literally at the final stage of polishing the code sample up. Once that's done (hopefully today) I'll write up a blog sample and a Wiki article on the WAML GitHub site to walk you and the rest of the community on how to pull this off. I'm personally really excited about this development and look forward to getting the information out there. Thanks for being so persistent with the team in motivating us to keep adding features to WAML!

Comment: Sounds good. Drop a tweet when its out. I already managed to get things working with a Native Application in the the portal. Just failed at doing it in a web app. Also right now, native clients cant be set for multi tenant and allowing 3th party people to use the native application. Only your own organization can be using it. Was trying the web app to see if more could be accomplished there. Looking forward to see your sample/walk-through.

Comment: Just found the blogpost that Brady mentioned and wanted to link it here: http://www.bradygaster.com/post/using-windows-azure-active-directory-to-authenticate-the-management-libraries